# How to find accumulated duration on several mp3 with command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, mp3

I have a directory with a lot of mp3 files, and I need a simple way to find the accumulated duration for them. I know that I can find the duration for one file with

```
ffmpeg -i <file> 2>&1 | grep Duration
```

I also know that I can run this command on all mp3 files in a directory with the command

```
for file in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep Duration; done
```

This can be somewhat filtered with

```
for file in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -f4 -d ' '; done
```

But how do I sum it all up? Using `ffmpeg` is not necessary. The output format is not so important either. Seconds or mm:ss or something similar will do. I would like it to look something like this:

```
$ <command>
84:33
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get exactly the duration in seconds, then sum them with bc:

```
for file in *.mp3;do ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file";done|paste -sd+|bc -l
```

Convert this number to HH:MM:SS format by yourself. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12199816/6481121

Comment: `date -d@$(for file in *.mp3; do ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file"; done | paste -sd+ | bc -l) -u +%H:%M:%S`

Comment: @DmitrySandalov This only works if the total duration is less than 24 hours. when I have 25:30:58 it gives 01:30:58. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[Ipors Sicer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480380/236940) worked perfectly. To add to his answer, I stripped everything after the dot and used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28451379/6699433) with a slight modification to get this:

```
secs=$(for file in *.mp3;
    do ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file";
done | paste -sd+|bc -l|cut -f1 -d '.'); 
printf '%d:%d\n' $(($secs/60)) $(($secs%60))
```

And I got this output:

```
87:2
```